# Attempting to utilize the Maven argument 'aether.connector.http.headers'

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, command-line-arguments, custom-headers

I am using Maven version 3.9.5. I'm attempting to execute a Maven command with the 'aether.connector.http.headers' configuration option to include custom headers in all the HTTP requests made during the Maven process. However, none of the headers I've set are visible in the requests when viewed through the configured proxy. My objective is to incorporate these custom headers into the Maven command without the need to modify settings.xml.

According to the documentation, it is expected to support all configuration options from Maven 3.9 onwards, as outlined in the following link: https://maven.apache.org/resolver/configuration.html

I executed the following command:

```
mvn install -Daether.connector.http.headers=key:value
```

Expected Outcome:
The HTTP request made during the Maven download dependencies process should include the header key:value.

Actual Outcome:
The custom header is not present in the request, as observed in the configured proxy. However, other general headers are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As property configuration `aether.connector.http.header` is a complex type you can not specific it as user property on command line.

For custom headers you need configure it in your `settings.xml`, example configuration in `settings.xml`:

```xml
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-server</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Foo</name>
            <value>Bar</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

More info: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html

Comment: Thank you! I still didn't get it, how is it possible to use this property if not from command line?

Comment: I added example code in answer - I hope it will be more clear

Comment: Tnx, and what about `aether.connector.http.headers`? It's not an argument that can be in use anywhere ?